# Creating SignUp page in SpringBoot but keep encountering "Whitelabel Error Page"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have started a basic springboot project and wanted to implement a sign up page but keep encountering whitelabel error page.

I have changed the folder the HTML files were in, no fix. using @RestController was a temporaroy fix that got rid of the whitelabel error page and just returned this "eturn "User signed up successfully!";"

Controller Class

```
package com.Kumar.signup.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import com.Kumar.signup.user.UserRepository;

import com.Kumar.signup.user.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public String signUp(@RequestBody User user, Model model) {
        System.out.println("Received user: " + user);
        userRepository.save(user);
        model.addAttribute("name", user.getUsername());
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

SignUp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h2>Sign Up</h2>
  <form action="/signup" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

User class

```
package com.Kumar.signup.user;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "_user")
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String username;

}
```

UserRepository

```
package com.Kumar.signup.user;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

greeting.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> //Thymeleaf is a template engine, there are others
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="|Hello, ${name}!|" />
</body>
</html>
```

My folder structure also seems fine:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/686mW.png)

Comment: Change your PostMapping to GetMapping you should see ur greeting

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line:

@Controller allows you to specify what HTML view to return, possibly with data in it. In the above example, if you use @Controller, you are not telling it what html view page to use, so you get a white label error.

@RestController returns a response directly. If you use @RestController, then you are telling it to return "User signed up successfully," that is your return value. I usually use Rest Controller for an API. Your return value for the signUp function is a string, this all makes sense.

Now, I assume what you want to do is have it return the HTML page. you need to specify the name of the HTML view page. You may even want to display the user saved data.

Also, you have a page for the input, you will need to have your controller specify a page of html that includes what you want to return.

If you just want a page that says "success" you can create a new HTML page that says that.

If you want to include user data, what you will need to do is get the User response from the successful repository call and add that to a model which will provide the data to complete a view.

Below is an example of setting data for a view that is similar to what you are trying to do.

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  @GetMapping("/greeting")
  public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "greeting"; // NAME OF THE VIEW
  }
}
```

the HTML would be in a page called "greeting.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> //Thymeleaf is a template engine, there are others
<head> 
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="|Hello, ${name}!|" />
</body>
</html>
```

example taken from this page, I would recommend reading the whole thing and adapting for what you are trying to do: https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content

Comment: I implemented the code you provided but I am still getting the same whitelabel error page

Comment: Don't implement it exactly, I offer this as a model, not a solution. IF you want a minimal solution, try this:
1 - create an HTML page called "success". IN addition to the headers, in the body just have <p> success!</p>
2 - annotate your controller with @Controller, have it return "success"
That should work for returning a page with no data. If you want data, try the link I posted above.

Comment: OK, you changed your code, I see what you're doing. You may need to add the Thymeleaf dependency. see here: https://www.thymeleaf.org/download.html

Comment: Try the minimal solution I mentioned above, then look to add detail. Perhaps your HTML view file is in the wrong place.